# Finding index of string in string array

Tags: arrays, string, vba, excel

[image][image][image]

This program removes a string from an array to a new sheet. I find the string 'hello' or 'bye' but I also want the string in the index before each of those strings. The string before 'hello' or 'bye' will not always be the same so how can the I use the Index() function?

```css
Sub SplitWithFormat()
    Dim R As Range, C As Range
    Dim i As Long, V As Variant
    Dim varHorizArray As Variant
    Dim rge As Range
    Dim intCol As Integer
   
Set R = Range("d1", Cells(Rows.Count, "d").End(xlUp))
For Each C In R
    With C
        .TextToColumns Destination:=.Range("AD1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        consecutivedelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, semicolon:=True, comma:=False, _
        Space:=True, other:=True, Otherchar:=vbLf

        Set rge = Selection
        varHorizArray = rge
        .Copy
        Range(.Range("AD1"), Cells(.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    End With
Next C

Application.CutCopyMode = False

    For intCol = LBound(varHorizArray, 2) To UBound(varHorizArray, 2)
       Debug.Print varHorizArray(1, intCol)
    Next intCol
    
       
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    varHorizArray = Array("bye","hello")
    Set NewSh = Worksheets.Add

    With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("AD1:AZ100")

        Rcount = 0

        For i = LBound(varHorizArray) To UBound(varHorizArray)

            
            Set Rng = .find(What:=varHorizArray(i), _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                FirstAddress = Rng.Address
                Do
                    Rcount = Rcount + 1

                    Rng.Copy NewSh.Range("A" & Rcount)

                    
                    NewSh.Range("A" & Rcount).Value = Rng.Value

                    Set Rng = .FindNext(Rng)
                Loop While Not Rng Is Nothing And Rng.Address <> FirstAddress
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Can you include both the current and expected results?

Comment: `dim s as string: s = left(1, range("d1").value, ", hello", vbtextcompare))` should do it. See [InStr function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1.aspx) to return the position of a search term within a longer string.

Comment: I updated the question @destination-data. The expected result would be the name coming before the string on the new sheet.

Comment: @Jeeped I tried that but it says "wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"

Comment: Where does the name come from?

Comment: @Kyle the picture of row 'D' is the first position, then the program creates an array that is another photo and the last step is where you see the 'hello' and 'bye'

Comment: It is very unclear to me what you are trying to accomplish. You want to take column "D" and strip out everything but the "Hello" or "Bye" part?

Comment: @Kyle first I create a new array then from that array I want to take all the 'hello' and 'bye' out along with the string that is in the position directly before either of those terms

Comment: What do you mean by "take them out"? To do what with them? I'm more concerned with where you start, and what you want, than your intermediate steps.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear.  I start with the cells in row D and split them into an array on the same sheet at AG. Then I search for the word "hello" or 'bye' and remove those to a new sheet on row A. The part that I'm having difficulty with is also removing the string before 'hello' or 'bye' to the new sheet as well. The bottom photo is the first step then the top is second and middle is last step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the [InStr function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1.aspx) is typically used to locate a substring within a string, your multiple search terms may be better handled with the [Split function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263365(v=vs.60).aspx).

```
Option Explicit

Sub stripName()
    Dim rw As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        For rw = 1 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
            .Cells(rw, "A") = Split(Split(.Cells(rw, "D").Value2, ", hello")(0), ", bye")(0)
        Next rw
    End With

End Sub
```

Note that the search terms use on the split are case-sensitive.

[image: split_names]

Addendum for revised question:

```
Option Explicit

Sub stripName()
    Dim rw As Long, s As String

    With ActiveSheet
        For rw = 1 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
            s = Split(.Cells(rw, "D").Value2, ", bye")(0)
            s = Split(s, ", hello")(0)
            s = Split(Chr(32) & s, Chr(32))(UBound(Split(Chr(32) & s, Chr(32))))
            .Cells(rw, "A") = s
        Next rw
    End With

End Sub
```

[image: split_names2]

Comment: I appreciate the help. This is sample data but if I were to have more strings in that cell how would I go about removing the 'hello' or 'bye' along with the word before it if it happened to be in the middle of a cell full of strings?

Comment: See my addendum above. Please make revisions to your original question or post a new question. Avoid making this a [Russian Doll Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188625).

Comment: I appreciate the help. I'll post a new question later and try your method.